# Code executes all cases even with break statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

This a simple program to rotate bits, the switch case used to define if the user wants a left rotating or right rotating after getting the most significant bit or the least significant bit depending on the choice I used for loop in side of switch and I used the same values and It execute all cases no mater what I entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE sizeof(number)*8

void main()
{
    int number, rotate, i, SB, numberr;
    char choice;

    puts("simple program to rotate bits of a number");
    printf("If you want right rotation type 'R'\n");
    printf("enter your number : ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter how much time you want to rotate : ");
    scanf("%d", &rotate);
    getchar();
    printf("IF you want left rotation type 'L' : ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch(choice)
        {
        case 'l' :
        case 'L' :
            SB = (1<<(SIZE-1))&1;
            for(i=0;i<rotate;i++)
                {
                numberr = (number << 1) | SB;
                printf("\n%d after being rotated %d times became %d\n\n", number, rotate, numberr);
                }
            break;
        case 'r' :
        case 'R' :
            SB = number & 1;
            for(i=0;i<rotate;i++)
                {
                numberr = (number >> 1) | SB;
                printf("\n%d after being rotated %d time became %d\n\n", number, rotate, numberr);
                }
            break;
        default :
            printf("please chose either R or L\n\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the language.

Comment: This code won't compile.  Please copy and paste the **exact** code you're running.

Comment: Do you only *think* it is executing all the cases because each one has the `printf` output *within* a loop (and with no newline either, to confuse further), rather than after the rotation is completed?

Comment: @dbush I copied the exact code can you check it now please

Comment: @WeatherVane no I had problems with copying the code here I fixed it now can you check again, and yes it is executing all cases

Comment: It isn't: after I added `L` and `R` to the otherwise identical messages, the fault can be seen to be what I suggested before: each case repeats the message, because it is ***inside the loop***.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're a life saver this is it thank very much can you add this as a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is confusing because the messages from each `case` are identically phrased. When I added `L` and `R` to the message, it showed that only one `case` is executed.

The problem is that the output is *within* the loop, and needs to be moved outside, for example

```
    case 'l' :
    case 'L' :
        SB = (1<<(SIZE-1))&1;
        for(i=0;i<rotate;i++)
            {
            numberr = (number << 1) | SB;
            }
        printf("L %d after being rotated %d times became %d\n\n", number, rotate, numberr);            
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refined your code and this might help.
You might want to improve the syntax of your code before posting the question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 32

int main() {
    int number, rotate, i, number1;
    char choice;
    int output;

    puts("simple program to rotate bits of a number");

    printf("enter your number : ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter how much time you want to rotate : ");
    scanf("%d", &rotate);
    printf("If you want right rotation type 'R'\n");
    printf("IF you want left rotation type 'L' : ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 'l' :
        case 'L' :
            output = (number << rotate) | (number >> (SIZE - rotate));
            printf("%d after rotating %d times became %d,",number,rotate,output);
            break;
        case 'r' :
        case 'R' :
            output = (number >> rotate) | (number << (SIZE - rotate));
            printf("%d after rotating %d times became %d,",number,rotate,output);
            break;
        default :
            printf("Please choose either R or L\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you if I may ask why it was executing all cases is that because we cant use for loop in side of switch or it was so many statements in side each case?

Comment: If this is your answer to the OP's question, please edit and **explain** what you found wrong in the OP's code and how you corrected it.

Comment: @UnderScore put a space before `%c` in `scanf("%c", &choice);` Like this `scanf(" %c",&choice);` . This is because the leading whitespace before `%c` skips all whitespace like character (including the \n stored by pressing previous ENTER key) and read the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: this is new for me so I don't need to add a getchar function thank you again